# how can i automate a website that returns dynamic selected elements

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, ui-automation

how can I automate a website like facebook that don't have id as selectable element and the class and other elements are dynamic I mean they change when the page is refreshed how do I automate this with selelium python

I have tried using the xpath but it did work, I also used the tag element for some buttons and its working correctly but there are other sections that don't have tag I am only left with class and xpath but the problem is that the class name changes anytime the page is refreshed.

Comment: Can you explain "tried using the xpath but it did work" in detail. Have a look at [ask] and [mcve] for additional information.

Comment: Do you understand they are doing this in part to prevent you from doing what you are doing, to protect their copyrighted property?  You're fighting a losing battle.